# can i crop a zoomed image . fixed cordinates

Tags: iphone, ios, image, crop

Problem : Can i crop a image at fixed coordinates(50,50,200,200) after zoom? I googling many hour and see matching question. but not get the Answer.

thanks.

my cropping logic is here..

```
CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, NO, 0);
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200);
[imageView1.image drawInRect:imageRect];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

but i cannot crop the exact image in scroll view. I wants crop image which is display in scrollView after zoom.

Comment: If you keep on asking same question,you wont get ans,just edit the original question.

Comment: @iApple i asked again in short. because previous question i ask is very detailed.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer of my own Question :** after googling i found a link. [here](http://aasims.wordpress.com/tag/uigraphicsgetimagefromcurrentimagecontext/) and after little modification it work fine for me.

May be it save other's time and effort. thanks

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(200, 200));

[scrollView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *fullScreenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

imageView1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(fullScreenshot, nil, nil, nil);

return fullScreenshot;
```

`import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h`  if warning in

`UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();`